# spring data mongorepository.save E11000 duplicate key error index sometimes

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have created app using jhipster where i am using `MongoRepository` to insert or save the document. But it throws exception sometimes but unable to figure out what could be the possible reason. I get the following exception on production i.e. ubuntu:

```
nested exception is com.mongodb.DuplicateKeyException: Write failed with 
error code 11000 and error message 'E11000 duplicate key error index: 
db_test.collection_test.$_id_ du
p key: { : "1212" }'
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:2114)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:464)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.saveDBObject(MongoTemplate.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doSave(MongoTemplate.java:1015)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:961)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.save(SimpleMongoRepository.java:80)
```

Following are the java code :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Document(collection = "collection_test")
public class CollectionTest implements Serializable {

@Id
private String id;

@Field("c_date")
@Indexed
private String cDate;

public CollctionTest() {
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCDate() {
    return cDate;
}

public void setCDate(String cDate) {
    this.cDate = cDate;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "CollctionTest{" +
            "id='" + id + '\'' +
            ", cDate='" + cDate + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

```
public interface CollectionTestRepository extends 
 MongoRepository<CollectionTest, String> {
}

@Component
public class CollectionTestService implements ICollectionTestService {

@Autowired
private CollectionTestRepository collectionTestRepository ;

public void saveOrUpdate(CollectionTest collectionTest ) {
    try {
        collectionTestRepository.save(collectionTest);
        LOGGER.info("Inserted document with id: " + collectionTest .getId() 
        + " into database");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception during save or update", ex);
    }
}

}
```

Note : This app consume collection test object through rabbitmq listener and call `saveOrUpdate()` method.

`_id` has the custom value from our generated values. If `_id` is already exists in the db just update the document else insert a new document. Used `MongoRepository.save()` for the same purpose

Answer (score 0):

this particular exception occurs from DB when you have a unique index in your DB and try to put duplicate data field.

First, you check your current unique indexes :

`db.collectionName.getIndexes()`

you try to update doc on specific id and putting duplicate data for your other indexing fields, in this case, DB throws an exception for the _id field index. although it's the wrong exception, it should show for a specific duplicate index name field but because you are doing update operation it shows on _id

in your coding, always remember that if you are using any unique index then before call saves first to get the particular collection on unique index keys, and then call update.

Comment: What? You mean the "primary key"? The error says `_id_` which is the primary key, and it's **always** there.  The "du" is truncated from "duplicate", which if you knew the subject matter you actually would have known

Comment: share your Indexes please

Comment: @Devratna I have not mentioned all fields above question but there are 5 indexes where each has unique name. `1`{ "v" : 1, "key" : {  "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "`_id_`", "ns" : "db_test.collection_test"},`2`{ "v" : 1, "key" : {  "c_date" : 1 }, "name" : "c_date", "ns" : "db_test.collection_test"},`3`{ "v" : 1, "key" : {  "c_name" : 1 }, "name" : "c_name", "ns" : "db_test.collection_test"},`4`{ "v" : 1, "key" : {  "c_number" : 1 }, "name" : "c_number", "ns" : "db_test.collection_test"},`5`{ "v" : 1, "key" : {  "status" : 1 }, "name" : "status", "ns" : "db_test.collection_test"}

Comment: that means when you try to update doc on specific id and put duplicate data for c_date or c_name or c_number or status, then DB throw an exception for the _id field although it's the wrong exception, it should show for specific duplicate index name field but because you are doing updation operation it shows on _id

Comment: I think if id is already exists it should just update the document regardless of values of other fields, But this error throws sometimes. We have approx 3 millions documents already inserted.

Comment: it updates but if in your updated data contain duplicate indexes data then this operation will fail and throw the exception of duplicate key error index

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172488/discussion-between-shan-and-devratna).